# Scheduled task not running manually

Tags: coldfusion

I created a `cfadmin` to run a scheduled task in the background. I actually created it as a chained task. My code is:

```
<cfschedule task="run" name="runthetask">
<cflocation addtoken="no" url="message.cfm">
```

I am sending the user to the `message.cfm` page, so as to make sure that I give them a message that page is being processed. Then I close the browser. However, the `cfschedular` never runs. The `coldfusion-out.log` shows it was called, but nothing happens. If I call it in browser, it works.

I want to run this task when I call it from my page. My page calls this `newpage.cfm` in browser, which contains the code above. So I am confused about why it is not working. What type of scheduled task should I add?

Comment: When you run it FROM the cfadmin does it work? (i.e. not in a browser). set the cfadmin to save the output to a file, run in the cfadmin and check the file contents.

Comment: yes, i had added a file, and it enters nothing in the file, i am lost what is happening

Comment: What is `runthetask` supposed to do?  What are you looking at that tells you it didn't do it?

Comment: i had created on page and had it registered in cfadmin, now using the task name, i call one another page which calls this taskname, and then at the bottom it navigates to another, the page which it calls is quite complex and takes around  min to complete, so i scheduled it run in background, but it does nothing

Comment: To get a page to run in the background, `cfthread` is probably more appropriate than `cfschedule`.

Comment: What is the nature of the task? What does it actually do?

Comment: it runs and collect information from database and create folders and call custom tag to create pdf's